# Send email with PHP script -> How to display mutated vowels?

Tags: php, mutated

I use this php script to send an email. It works well, but german mutated vowels (ö,ä,ü, etc) are not displayed correctly. Any hints how to change that?

```
<?php

/* Geben Sie hier Ihre E-Mail Adresse zwischen den beiden " an: */

$_emails[0] = "mail@blablablabla.li";

// Wenn keine $_POST Daten übermittelt wurden, dann abbrechen
if(!isset($_POST) OR empty($_POST))
{
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    echo "Es wurden keine Daten übermittelt!";
    exit;
}
else
{
    // Datum, Uhrzeit und Pfad zum eigenen Script feststellen
    $date = date("d.m.Y");
    $time = date("H:i");
    $host = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    // Empfänger feststellen und auf Gültigkeit prüfen
    if(isset($_POST['recipient']) AND isset($_emails[ $_POST['recipient'] ])
       AND preg_match("/^.*@.*\..*$/", $_emails[ $_POST['recipient'] ]))
    {
        $recipient = $_emails[ $_POST['recipient'] ];
    }
    // Wurde kein (gültiger) Empfänger angegeben, es mit $_email[0] versuchen
    elseif(isset($_emails[0]) AND preg_match("/^.*@.*\..*$/", $_emails[0]))
    {
        $recipient = $_emails[0];
    }
    // Ist auch diese Adresse ungültig, mit Fehlermeldung abbrechen
    else
    {
        header("Content-type: text/plain");
        echo "Fehler im Script - es wurde kein Empfänger oder eine ungültige E-Mail Adresse in \ angegeben.";
        exit;
    }

    // Wenn Betreff übermittelt, diesen verwenden
    if(isset($_POST['subject']))
    {
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    }
    // sonst einen Default Betreff verwenden
    else
    {
        $subject = "Formular Daten von {$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}";
    }

    // E-Mai Kopf generieren
    $email = "Formular Eintrag\n"
           . "\n"
           . "Am $date um $time Uhr hast das Script auf $host Formulardaten empfangen,\n"
           . "welche nach Angabe des Browsers von {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']} stammen.\n"
           . "\n"
           . "Der Formular Inhalt wird nachfolgend wiedergegeben.\n"
           . "\n";

    // Alle $_POST Werte an den E-Mail Kopf anhängen
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        if($key == "redirect" OR $key == "recipient" OR $key == "subject")
        {
            continue;
        }
        $email .= "Fomular Feld '$key':\n"
               .  "=============================\n"
               .  "$value\n"
               .  "\n";
    }

    // E-Mail Fuß anfügen
    $email .= "=============================\n"
           .  "Ende der automatisch generierten E-Mail.";

    // Versuchen E-Mail zu versenden
    if(!mail($recipient, $subject, $email)) {
        // Ist dies gescheitert, Fehlermeldung ausgeben
        echo "Es ist ein Fehler beim Versenden der E-Mail aufgetreten,"
             . " eventuell liegt ein Konfigurationsfehler am Server vor.\n\n";
        exit;
    }

    // Wenn gewünscht, auf Bestätigungsseite weiterleiten
    if(isset($_POST['redirect']) AND preg_match("=^(http|ftp)://.*\..*$=", $_POST['redirect'])) {
       header("Location: ".$_POST['redirect']);
        exit;
    } else {
        header("Content-type: text/html");
        echo "Die E-Mail wurde erfolgreich versendet.";
    echo '<br>';
      echo '<a href="http://www.ovlu.li/cms/index.php?page=kontakt">Zurueck</a>';
        exit;
    }
}

?>
```

So i followed the hint in the first answer and the code looks now the following:

```
<?php

/* Geben Sie hier Ihre E-Mail Adresse zwischen den beiden " an: */

$_emails[0] = "bla@bla.li";

// Wenn keine $_POST Daten übermittelt wurden, dann abbrechen
if(!isset($_POST) OR empty($_POST))
{
   header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    echo "Es wurden keine Daten übermittelt!";
    exit;
}
else
{
    // Datum, Uhrzeit und Pfad zum eigenen Script feststellen
    $date = date("d.m.Y");
    $time = date("H:i");
    $host = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    // Empfänger feststellen und auf Gültigkeit prüfen
    if(isset($_POST['recipient']) AND isset($_emails[ $_POST['recipient'] ])
       AND preg_match("/^.*@.*\..*$/", $_emails[ $_POST['recipient'] ]))
    {
        $recipient = $_emails[ $_POST['recipient'] ];
    }
    // Wurde kein (gültiger) Empfänger angegeben, es mit $_email[0] versuchen
    elseif(isset($_emails[0]) AND preg_match("/^.*@.*\..*$/", $_emails[0]))
    {
        $recipient = $_emails[0];
    }
    // Ist auch diese Adresse ungültig, mit Fehlermeldung abbrechen
    else
    {
        header("Content-type: text/plain");
        echo "Fehler im Script - es wurde kein Empfänger oder eine ungültige E-Mail Adresse in \ angegeben.";
        exit;
    }

    // Wenn Betreff übermittelt, diesen verwenden
    if(isset($_POST['subject']))
    {
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    }
    // sonst einen Default Betreff verwenden
    else
    {
        $subject = "Formular Daten von {$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}";
    }

    // E-Mai Kopf generieren
    $email = "Formular Eintrag\n"
           . "\n"
           . "Am $date um $time Uhr hast das Script auf $host Formulardaten empfangen,\n"
           . "welche nach Angabe des Browsers von {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']} stammen.\n"
           . "\n"
           . "Der Formular Inhalt wird nachfolgend wiedergegeben.\n"
           . "\n";

    // Alle $_POST Werte an den E-Mail Kopf anhängen
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        if($key == "redirect" OR $key == "recipient" OR $key == "subject")
        {
            continue;
        }
        $email .= "Fomular Feld '$key':\n"
               .  "=============================\n"
               .  "$value\n"
               .  "\n";
    }

    // E-Mail Fuß anfügen
    $email .= "=============================\n"
           .  "Ende der automatisch generierten E-Mail.";

$email = htmlentities($email, ENT_QUOTES, 'uft-8');

    // Versuchen E-Mail zu versenden
    if(!mail($recipient, $subject, $email))
    {
        // Ist dies gescheitert, Fehlermeldung ausgeben
        echo "Es ist ein Fehler beim Versenden der E-Mail aufgetreten,"
             . " eventuell liegt ein Konfigurationsfehler am Server vor.\n\n";
        exit;
    }

    // Wenn gewünscht, auf Bestätigungsseite weiterleiten
    if(isset($_POST['redirect']) AND preg_match("=^(http|ftp)://.*\..*$=", $_POST['redirect']))
    {
       header("Location: ".$_POST['redirect']);
        exit;
    }
    // sonst eine Bestätigung ausgeben
    else
    {
        header("Content-type: text/html");
        echo "Die E-Mail wurde erfolgreich versendet.";
    echo '<br>';
      echo '<a href="http://foto.roser.li/admin/index.php?page=kontakt">Zurueck</a>';
        exit;
    }
}

?>
```

Now when I send the email, the following message is displayed:

```
> Warning: htmlentities(): charset
> `uft-8' not supported, assuming
> iso-8859-1 in
> /home/www/web21/html/roser/foto/admin/mail.php
> on line 77 Die E-Mail wurde
> erfolgreich versendet.
```

Comment: This is an encoding issue. Mandatory basic reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Have you looked at my answer below? I had the same problem a year ago, difference is I create the whole email, while you use the mail function, but it should work. Email has it's own structure and way of defining content. What you're doing is HTTP encoding stuff. Read the RFC's onhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME, for more info.

Comment: hi. sry not yet. was on a hike for some days. ill do it today or tomorrow. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try the `utf-8` charset in your header for content type:

```
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

Also, use **[`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)** function for your email content:

```
$email = htmlentities($email, ENT_QUOTES, 'uft-8');
```

Comment: @Sebi: You are already using that line, just replace it with `header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");`. Hope that works.

Comment: so i tested it with replacing the header. this doesn't work. now i will test to use your htmlentities, but there i have to check where to replace it...

Answer (score 0):

Now, assuming that you have data saved right, this is how you could try the following.

```
$subject = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($newsletter->subject) . "?=";
```

The idea here is to get the raw email subject line to look as such:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?base64_encoded_subject?=\r\n;
```

For the body,

```
$email = 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ISO-8859-1"' . "\r\n\r\n";
$email .= $email;
```

The idea is to have the email content proceeded by it's character set. That does it for me.

To get the posted data right, you will want to set the page encoding using the content/type header.

```
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

Hope it works for you, it's been quite a while since I used the php mail function You might want to give [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) a look.